# Using the new io.FS to fs.WalkDir & list files across filesystem types

Tags: go, io

Im using the kind of new io.FS abstraction to walk through a file system and read the first 128 bytes of each file that matches a file extension we have internally.

The files are in a local file system and archive files etc (ZIP and Tar I thunk).

I am using fs.WalkDir, passing in an fs.FS (os.DIR and fstest.MapFS in my tests). When walking I return an array of 'files' (really they are *.pzix and *.pzi files which are our propietary formats). I cannot find a suitable way of using the FS interface to get a few things about the file I am dealing with.

I want to:

- Get the filename
- Get the filesize
- Get the openfile method

I am finding the interfaces in Go a bit confusing coming from Java/C#. I was hoping to operate on the abstractions but I cannot figure out how to get other implementations of the file itself (eg. File interfaces have Stat() and read).

The simplest thing I've found is to store the path and the filename in the array and then when I iterate through the array, determine whether it was a os.Dir or fstest.MapFS but it seems rather counter intuitive:

```
func collectFiles(f fs.FS, root string) []string {
 var files []string
 fs.WalkDir(f, ".", func(p string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
  if !d.IsDir() { // we also check a few other things in the filename here
   f = filepath.Abs(path.Join(root, p))
   files = append(files, f)
  }
 }
 return files
}
```

This gives me:

```
root = "m://" // mapfs
files = { "m://id-198271.pzi", "m://id-7125-092581.pzix"}
```

Is there a smarter way for me to deal with the abstractions and not do these things? Because after the array is returned, I have to 'open' the file, read the first 128 bytes (signature) and hash the rest of the file to make sure its 'valid'.

EDIT: To clarify, the `collectFiles` method is creating our main hit list of files to work on in another method. I was hoping to pass in local system files, zip files and tar files into that method so it can iterate through the files within the archives and add them to the array.

Was hoping there'd be like a File interface I can store in the array instead of a string so that subsequent callers can do f.open() without knowing what the underlying thing is.

Comment: `FS` supports `Open`, so you can `f.Open` the file, and then check if the returned file implements `io.Reader`. If so, you can read the 128 bytes, and close it. Based on your description, file should implement `io.Reader`, so you can do `reader := file.(io.Reader)` and then call `reader.Read(...)`

Comment: That's clever! I didn't know about that :) thanks. My biggest gripe is that we decouple walking and reading, so the walking just gets us a huge list of files we need to trawl through - and that list is a mix of local files, and files within TARs/ZIPs as well. What would you suggest I return in that array so I don't need the subsequent users of fs.FS to know the underlying implementation?

Comment: You can't open a huge number of files. So if you are not going to process them as you walk, you can return a slice where each element is a struct containing a reference to `fs` and the file name. With those two, you can open and read the files one by one.

Comment: thanks you both came to the same conclusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get the filename

`p` is the name within the file system.

> Get the filesize

Get the size by calling `fs.Stat(f, p)`

> Get the openfile method

Open the file with `f.Open(p)`

Example:

```
f := os.DirFS("/etc")
fs.WalkDir(f, ".", func(p string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
    if !d.IsDir() {
        st, _ := fs.Stat(f, p)
        r, _ := f.Open(p)
        defer r.Close()

        // Read prefix
        var buf [md5.Size]byte
        n, _ := io.ReadFull(r, buf[:])

        // Hash remainder
        h := md5.New()
        _, _ = io.Copy(h, r)
        s := h.Sum(nil)

        fmt.Printf("%s %d %x %x\n", p, st.Size(), buf[:n], s)
    }
    return nil
})
```

For brevity, the example ignores errors. Don't do that in real code.

https://go.dev/play/p/W7He_YNSZFU

Comment: Thanks that's excellent! I should clarify, p does give me the filename (within the current filesystem). But as I mentioned above, I'm creating a list of files to unpack and calculate financial data off that have different sources. So some are os.DirFS, some are Zip and some are Tar files. I'd like the walk & subsequent readers (outside of the WalkDir func) to not know about the ZIP/TAR and just read...

Comment: @AliciaWentworth Do the work inside the walk function (as shown here) or create slice of `type struct NameFS { name string; fsys fs.FS }` and use name and fsys do do the work outside the walk function. https://go.dev/play/p/LSNttserRA3

Comment: thanks i've seen that in another project and thought that might be the ticket. Thanks.